# Display another button with autocomplete in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm tring to do a autocomplete from json url, it works good.

Now what I want, it's when I click to the autocomplete, I want to display the import button and if input is empty or we put a new value (not in the import), display the create button.

Give you a example on what i'm doing with some datas:

```js
$('#search-deal').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    var data =[{
        "id": 1671,
        "title": "Queens Park Tyres deal"
      }, {
        "id": 1672,
        "title": "Wildman Craft Lager deal"
      }, {
        "id": 1673,
        "title": "General Store deal"
      }, {
        "id": 1674,
        "title": "Deluxe Off Licence deal"
      }, {
        "id": 1675,
        "title": "Ahmed Halal Bazaar deal"
      }];
    
    var datamap = data.map(function(i) {
      return {
        label: i.id + ' - ' + i.title,
        value: i.id + ' - ' + i.title,
        desc: i.title
      }
    });
    
    var key = request.term;
    
    datamap = datamap.filter(function(i) {
      if(i.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) >= 0){
        document.getElementById("create").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("import").style.visibility = 'visible';
        return i.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
          };
    });

    response(datamap);
  },
  minLength: 1,
  delay: 100
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="search-deal" />
<button id="create" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Créer une affaire</button>
<button id="import" type="submit" style="visibility:hidden" class="btn btn-primary">Importer</button>
```

The problem here, it's when I write "p", the button import show up and I want to show up only when I click to the autocomplete.
The second problem, it's the button create nevere come back if value is empty or put another value

Anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand from the shared snippet that you are using `jquery ui autocomplete`.
I would suggest following changes/updates to your code

1. For changing button display on selecting the autocomplete item, use `select` event. https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select
2. Whenever user types something, hide the import button. Display it only when an item is selected.
3. For handling empty input case, use `oninput` event.

I have made following changes to the code you shared

1. Added a new function to handle button toggle
2. Hide the import button from `source` property i.e. when user type some input and also when input box is blank
3. Show the import button when user selects an autocomplete option

**Working code link:**  https://plnkr.co/edit/PgzUuOADhIqk9zbl?preview

I hope this solves your issue